# Lazy mount of remote filesystem (with sshfs)

Tags: ssh, mount, automounting, sshfs

I have a remote computer, and I mount its filesystem with sshfs to my local folder `~/user@host`, like that:

```
sshfs user@host: ~/user@host
```

Works nice, but I want to implement "lazy" mount: i.e. I don't want it to be mounted at system startup, but I want it to be mounted just when I'm trying to open my local folder `~/user@host` .

Probably there is some way to define like "filesystem hooks": just when user requests directory contents, some command should be executed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're describing autofs. Autofs mounts filesystems on demand, that is, when you try to access them. According to this Arch wiki page, it should work with sshfs. 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs#FTP_and_SSH_.28with_FUSE.29

Comment: Thank you, it looks like exactly what I need (but I'll check later)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sshfs` has a `-o delay_connect` option now, which is hopefully much easier to deal with than setting up autofs.